# Help solving a problem on Matrix Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ be an upper triangular matrix. I need to show that $A$ is nilpotent if and only if all the elements on the diagonal of $A$ are zero.

I started by showing one direction:

- $(\Rightarrow)$ If $A$ is nilpotent there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $A^{k}=0$. Since $A$ is a triangular matrix, then the powers of $A$ have the elements on the diagonal given by

$$(A^{k})_{ii}=(A)_{ii}^k$$

Since $A^{k}=0$ then $(A)_{ii}^{k}=0$, which implies that $A_{ii}=0$.

I have difficulties to show the other direction $(\Leftarrow)$ of this theorem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just realized that the theorem of Cayley Hamilton could be useful.

Comment: Hint: show that for a zero-diagonal upper triangular matrix, the matrix $A^2$ has zero elements on the next diagonal, $(A^2)_{ij}=0$ for $j=i+1$.

Comment: Yes, Cayley-Hamilton is a way to go.

Comment: Ok Thanks that is clear for me @daw

Comment: Show that the image of $A^k$ is in the subspace spanned by $e_1,\ldots, e_{n-k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an upper triangular matrix. Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are the elements $a_{ii}$ on the diagonal of $A$.

Then $A$ is nilpotent $ \iff $ the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0 \iff a_{ii}=0$ for all $i \in \{1,2,...,n\}.$

Answer (score 1):

Diagonal entries zero and upper triangular $\implies c_A(x)=x^n\implies$ by Cayley-Hamilton that $A^n=0$.